# How to import local Go package in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, go

How to import local packages in Golang + GAE?

I wanna something like this:

```
app/
-app.yaml
-/my_app
--my_app.go
--/package1
---package1.go
```

Listing of my_app.go:

```
package my_app

import (
  "http"
  "./package1"
)

func init() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", package1.index)
}
```

Listing of package1.go:

```
package package1

import (
  "http"
  "fmt"
)

func index (w http.ResponseWriter, r * http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprint(w, "I'm index page =) ")
}
```

I this case I have an error like:

```
/path/to/project/my_app/my_app.go:5: can't find import: ./package1
2011/11/03 10:50:51 go-app-builder: Failed building app: failed running 6g: exit status 1
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You either need to link or copy the packages to your application directory.</strike> The path relative to the root of the application directory should match the import path. <strike>To use package1, you should configure your app directory to look like this:</strike>

```
app.yaml
yourapp/yourapp.go
package1/package1.go
```

from https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/coEvrWIJGTs/75GzcefKVcIJ

Comment: For a real live example check https://github.com/haarts/flipco.in which uses the external Mustache lib.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're wrong. I've found answer on my question. If I wanna add package into my_app/package1, I should write import "my_app/package1". Thanks for answer.

Comment: hay I'm wrong oups. Please note the "you should" in my respond as, this is what I would do in-place of mixing the package1 import with my_app

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the comments to dupoxy's answer, the way to import a local package in the given situation is to import as `"my_app/package1"`:

```
import (
    "http"
    "my_app/package1"
)
```

Comment: Note however that you can then not compile/run your program like normal because a relative import path like that will not work outside of GAE. You can make a "hybrid" app with a ```+build !appengine``` build flag on a ```main.go``` file (for example) that then imports using the full package path. Then your GAE go file would have the opposite, ```+build appengine``` to exclude it from the normal go build process. It's a little annoying but works.