# Why can't I deploy with 'goapp deploy' to GAE, I get can't find import: "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, deployment, go

**Main problem:  can't deploy with 'goapp deploy' to GAE, keep getting this message:**

src/mygoprog.go:11: can't find import: "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

I have deployed 'hello world' program that listens on port 8080 to GAE with no problems; now trying to deploy a more sophisticated program.

This works just fine to test locally:
C:\mysql\src>go run mygoprog.go

This does not when trying to deploy to GAE:
C:\mysql>goapp deploy

I've reinstalled goappengine and go language from scratch with cleaned up registry between uninstall and install.
Any help would be appreciated.

github install command(s):
goapp get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
also tried
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

Source code (I've tried moving it around, the error follows the move to line 11 or 2 or whatever):

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)
import  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

Environment:
Python 2.7
Windows 7 - 64 bit
goappengine sdk version 1.9.1
mercurial 2.9.1

Environment variables:
GOPATH=C:\mysql\
GOROOT=C:\Go\

app.yml contents:
application: skilled-nation-521 
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This does not work:
C:\mysql>goapp deploy

```
Results:
05:20 PM Application: skilled-nation-521; version: 1
05:20 PM Host: appengine.google.com
05:20 PM
Starting update of app: skilled-nation-521, version: 1
05:20 PM Getting current resource limits.
05:20 PM Scanning files on local disk.
05:20 PM Cloning 23 application files.
05:20 PM Compilation starting.
05:20 PM Compilation: 16 files left.
05:20 PM Error 422: --- begin server output ---
Compile failed:
2014/03/26 15:20:24 go-app-builder: build timing: 2├ù6g (171.487931ms total), 2├gopack (61.001119ms total), 0├ù6l (0 total)
2014/03/26 15:20:24 go-app-builder: failed running 6g: exit status 1



src/mygoprog.go:11: can't find import: "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
--- end server output ---
05:20 PM Rolling back the update.
Error 422: --- begin server output ---
```

--- end server output ---
error while running appcfg.py: exit status 1

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Directory structure of c:\mysql:

```
C:\mysql>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is D2E8-63AC

 Directory of C:\mysql

03/26/2014  05:14 PM    <DIR>          .
03/26/2014  05:14 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/25/2014  04:17 PM               119 app.yaml
03/26/2014  05:14 PM    <DIR>          pkg
03/26/2014  05:17 PM    <DIR>          src
               1 File(s)            119 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  20,781,137,920 bytes 


C:\mysql>cd src

C:\mysql\src>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is D2E8-63AC

 Directory of C:\mysql\src

03/26/2014  05:17 PM    <DIR>          .
03/26/2014  05:17 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/26/2014  05:14 PM    <DIR>          github.com
03/26/2014  05:14 PM             2,666 mygoprog.go
               1 File(s)          2,666 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  20,781,387,776 bytes free

C:\mysql\src>cd github.com

C:\mysql\src\github.com>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is D2E8-63AC

 Directory of C:\mysql\src\github.com

03/26/2014  05:14 PM    <DIR>          .
03/26/2014  05:14 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/26/2014  05:14 PM    <DIR>          go-sql-driver
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  20,781,387,776 bytes free
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: I know next to zero about Go (just heard a podcast on it this morning), but looking at http://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackagePaths I wonder whether the underscore you have before the package path in your import statement is causing the issue?

Comment: Still no joy with or without the underscore.  The code examples for that package around the net have the underscore.

Comment: Set GOOS and GOARCH in GOAPP.BAT in GAE directory, still doesn't work                                                           C:\mysql>go env
set GOARCH=amd64  
set GOBIN=  
set GOCHAR=6  
set GOEXE=.exe  
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64  
set GOHOSTOS=windows  
set GOOS=windows  
set GOPATH=C:\mysql\  
set GORACE=  
set GOROOT=C:\Go  
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64  
set TERM=dumb  
set CC=gcc  
set GOGCCFLAGS=-g -O2 -m64 -mthreads  
set CXX=g++  
set CGO_ENABLED=1

Answer (score 1):

The import path must work from the folder where the app.yaml resides. So you need to move the github.com folder up there. (Similar question: [How to import local Golang package in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989799/how-to-import-local-golang-package-in-gae))

Note: You should never test your App Engine stuff with the go executable, always use the goapp tool.